# How to keep top 3 rows of each group in a pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, grouping

I have a list that looks like this:

```
var1     var2    count
 A        abc      4
 A        abc      3
 A        abc      2
 A        abc      1
 A        abc      1
 B        abc      7
 B        abc      5
 B        abc      2
 B        abc      1
 B        abc      1
 C        abc      4
 C        abc      3
 C        abc      2
 C        abc      1
 C        abc      1

 ....
```

I want to create a new dataframe with top 3 'count' results from each group. It should look like this:

```
     var1     var2    count
      A        abc      4
      A        abc      3
      A        abc      2
      B        abc      7
      B        abc      5
      B        abc      2
      C        abc      4
      C        abc      3
      C        abc      2
      ....
```

Is there a convenient way to do this in Python using head()?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Solution with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), `groupby` and [`SeriesGroupBy.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nlargest.html):

```
df = df.set_index('var2').groupby("var1")['count'].nlargest(3).reset_index()
print (df)
  var1 var2  count
0    A  abc      4
1    A  abc      3
2    A  abc      2
3    B  abc      7
4    B  abc      5
5    B  abc      2
6    C  abc      4
7    C  abc      3
8    C  abc      2
```

Answer (score 8):

If the *count* column has been sorted in descending order, then you can just use `groupby.head` to take the first three rows from each group:

```
df.groupby("var1").head(3)
```

[image]

Otherwise, you can group data frame by `var1` and use `nlargest` to retrieve the three rows with top 3 counts:

```
df.groupby("var1", group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g.nlargest(3, "count"))
```

[image]